# Android Kotlin : What does return@onClicklistener does?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

What does `return@onClicklistener` does in the below mentioned code

```
if (password.isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Missing password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    return@OnClickListener
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return@OnClickListener` means that the `OnClickListener` which is set on the `View` shouldn't execute the code after this statement, but outside the `OnClickListener` the flow will still remain the same.

Does that answer your question? :)

Comment: Nice to hear that, you can accept either mine or @mightyWOZ solution to let others know that this question doesn't need any more help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [labeled return](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-at-labels), contrary to normal `return` statment which by default returns from the nearest enclosing `function` or anonymous function, a labeled `return` returns from the lable specified after @.

In your case the label is `OnClickListener` which is implicit.